# how to enable the foreground to scroll vertically but not the background

Tags: html, css, scroll, scrollbar

like in twitter for example, when I open up a profile summary of other person, the right sroll bar only scrolling the profile summary window (the foreground) not the web page behind it (the background). how can i do this, any suggestions? Many thanks.

Comment: can you post the code you have tried?

Comment: @ani don't forget to mark a correct answer when you're happy with one ;)

Answer (score 0):

If you are referring to a modal popup you need to apply `overflow: hidden;` to the `body` tag when the modal is open.

You could detect when the popup has been opened. When it is you can set a class to the body tag e.g. `modalOpen` with the correct styling. Then remove this class when the modal closes.

**EDIT/ADDITION:**
If you need to force the popup to scroll then apply `overflow-y: scroll;` to it.

Comment: Hi Dave, your solution only to hiding the scroll bar when the popup appears but the popup it self can't be scoll. do you know how I'm able to scroll the popup too? Txs

Comment: Typically you need to apply overflow-y: scroll; What exactly is happening in your popup that means it isnt scrolling? Is the content just being cutoff? Maybe you need to apply a height/maxheight to the popup to activate the scroll? OR maybe there isnt enough content in the popup so it doesnt have to scroll ;) If you upload some code to your question, or setup a jsfiddle to show the issues youre having I can tell you a more accurate solution

Answer (score 0):

Continuing on Dave sugestion, I'm adding one more thing. after the popup appears I simply `overflow-y','scroll` the popup so it can be scroll vertically and when it close `overflow-y','hidden`. Many thanks all.